# entity framework unit of work in winforms

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, web-to-winforms

I found this sample but its for web. Can any one check this proj. and add a simple sample using winforms(no wpf).

[Source Code](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=436ece247fd754d6&resid=436ECE247FD754D6!134&parid=436ECE247FD754D6!132&authkey=!AIoweKyWXP-dSpI)

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of problem were you facing? Anyways I have made sample (yet basic) structure of how you can achieve this in WinForm. I have done using sort of Model View Presenter pattern.

First of all we have a presenter, which would deal with unit of work almost similarly the way controller does

```
internal class EmployeePresenter
{
    private readonly IEmployeeFormView _employeeFormView;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public EmployeePresenter(IEmployeeFormView view)
    {
        _employeeFormView = view;
        _unitOfWork = new SqlUnitOfWork();
    }

    internal void GetData()
    {
        var id = 1; //parameter
        var employee = _unitOfWork.Employees.Single(e => e.Id == id);
        _employeeFormView.PopulateData(employee.Name);
    }
}
```

Then we have an interface and a form implementing that interface

```
public interface IEmployeeFormView
{
    void PopulateData(string data);
}

public partial class EmployeeForm : Form, IEmployeeFormView
{
    private readonly EmployeePresenter _presenter;

    public EmployeeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = new EmployeePresenter(this);
    }

    #region IEmployeeFormView Members

    public void PopulateData(string data)
    {
        txtName.Text = data; //txtName is a textbox on form
    }

    #endregion

    private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.GetData();
    }
}
```

Add the required reference and you are done. This might not be the best way but it's certainly a way to achieve this.

Solution is upload [here](http://www.box.com/s/cafa9dc1794ebb3811d2).

Hope this helps. Please feel free to discuss, if required.

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge. If you don't mind can you upload a sample using this two patterns uow and repository and bind the form without mvp pattern

Comment: okay I have made a simpleForm in the project and uploaded solution [here](http://www.box.com/s/f301bfca099c082d059f)

Comment: Hi once again,

I have converted this project to vb.net but when i run the project the following error appears:

Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'EmployeeDomain.Employee'.